# Angular.js Error: Multiple directives [tagManager, tagManager] asking for isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gruntjs, yeoman

I've made an Angular.js app and scaffolded the `Grunt` build using `yeoman`. The app works fine in development, but when I build and deploy to a staging server I get errors on all directives (own and 3rd party): examples

```
Error: Multiple directives [tagManager, tagManager] asking for isolated scope on: <tag-manager tags="profile.styles" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
```

and

```
Error: Multiple directives [gender, gender] asking for template on: <gender value="profile.gender">
```

I think the directives are fine since they work in development, but something is happening in the (yeoman) build?

For reference here is one directive (in coffee-script)

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .directive 'gender', [->
    template: '<span><i class="{{icon}} {{color}}"></i></span>'
    restrict: 'EA'
    scope:
      value: '=',
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      if scope.value is 'male'
        scope.icon = 'icon-male'
        scope.color = 'blue_fg'
      else
        scope.icon = 'icon-female'
        scope.color = 'pink_fg'
  ]
```

Comment: Your build process is duplicating your directives (and probably the rest of the codebase as well).

Comment: Awesome Stewie. You are indeed right. Because I write in Coffee script  each source file was included twice in the build. Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem and this pointed me towards the solution. Thanks a lot! (karma seemed to remember the old instance of a file that had been moved to another location. Restarting karma did the job).

Comment: I also had a similar problem, but because I had both `template:` and `templateUrl:` on the same directive and forgot to remove one.